# Hide directories from friendly url

Tags: mod-rewrite

How would I go about removing two directories with the following rule?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^/subdir/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /subdir/jadehttp.dll?Www_MySite&Action01=$1&H04=$2&cats=$3&states=$4 [L,NC]
```

Currently the friendly url successfully outputs to `http://mysite.com/subdir/landingpage/1/packages/vic`.
I want it to look like: `http://mysite.com/subdir/packages/vic`
Any ideas?

Comment: So what's the difference between the `http://mysite.com/subdir/landingpage/1/packages/vic` and `http://mysite.com/subdir/landingpage/1/packages/vic`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please see the edit to how I want the URL to look

Comment: So it's cool if the `/subdir/jadehttp.dll` doesn't get the parameters for `Action01` and `H04`?

Comment: But could you also show me what it would look like if it had to get the parameters for Action01 and H04 but hidden from the newly passed url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your existing rules, which are fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^/subdir/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /subdir/jadehttp.dll?Www_MySite&Action01=$1&H04=$2&cats=$3&states=$4 [L,NC]
```

Then add these *after* them to account for 2 missing path nodes in the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^/subdir/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /subdir/jadehttp.dll?Www_MySite&cats=$1&states=$2 [L,NC]
```

That rule will take a URL request like `http://mysite.com/subdir/packages/vic` and internally rewrite it to `/subdir/jadehttp.dll?Www_MySite&cats=packages&states=vic`. The **Action01** and **H04** parameters are thus lost.

> could you also show me what it would look like if it had to get the parameters for Action01 and H04 but hidden from the newly passed url?

You can embed some defaults, say for example:

```
RewriteRule ^/subdir/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /subdir/jadehttp.dll?Www_MySite&Action01=FOO&H04=BAR&cats=$1&states=$2 [L,NC]
```

replacing the `FOO` and `BAR` with some default values. But since there's nothing else in the URI to extract from, you can't get those parameters from the URI. If they're not part of the URI, there's nothing else to extract them from.